# With is this Observable in my Angular 2 App Not Working?

Tags: javascript, angular, socket.io, observable

I am trying to convert a rest http observable with a socket.io-based observable in my Angular 2 app. The rest observable works as is. And with the socket option, I am getting closer, but right now I'm getting an error saying the observable I'm using for sockets expects an object, rather than an array. And I need it to be an array to be able to iterate over the data items.

First off, here's the original http, rest observable function from my service (this IS working):

```
getByGroup() {
    return this._http.get(this._url)
        .map((response: Response) => response.json())
        .catch(this._errorsHandler);
}
_errorsHandler(error: Response) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
}
```

And in the component I am subscribing to this like this:

```
   this.clientService.getByGroup()
        .subscribe(resRecordsData => this.records = resRecordsData,
        responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError);
```

I have "records" declared as an empty array in the component. I am then using the result of the observable, which is assigned to "records", to print to the view. All the above works perfectly.

Now this is what I'm trying to do with the socket-based observable (this is not working - and it's expecting an object rather than an array) -- I need help understanding why:

```
getByGroup() {
    const observable = new Observable(observer => {
    this.socket = io(this._url);
    this.socket.on('getByStage', (data) => {
        return data;
    });
        return () => {
            this.socket.disconnect();
        };
    });
    return observable;
}
```

Again, I'm trying to subscribe to this observable the same way, like this:

```
   this.clientService.getByGroup()
        .subscribe(resRecordsData => this.records = resRecordsData,
        responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError);
```

But again, it's not working in this second instance, because I'm getting an error saying:

> Type '{}' is not assignable to type '[]any'.

So how can I handle this? How can I finagle the service socket call to expect an array instead of an object? It's not clear to me why it's expecting an object to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `data` is an array then the following should compile and work:

```
getByGroup():Observable<any[]> {
    const observable = new Observable<any[]>(observer => {
    this.socket = io(this._url);
    this.socket.on('getByStage', (data) => {
        observer.next(data);
    });
        return () => {
            this.socket.disconnect();
        };
    });
    return observable;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Something's still causing an issue - but my guess is it's something on the api side for our socket functions. What you have here looks right. Re: your response, so is that the key: you have to explicitly declare the Observable to be of type "any[]", otherwise it will implicitly return an object? Just wondering why that wasn't an issue with my original call?

Comment: TypeScript uses type inferring and in your case inferred types were incompatible so i explicitly put types.

Comment: Okay, got it. Thanks.